# How to do a Like comparison with [ ]

Tags: powershell, comparison

How do I do a `-like` comparison with a string like `[TEST]`?  It does not work, when I do like this `"[TEST]"`.

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_TaskSequencePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer | 
    Where-Object {$_.name -like "*[TEST]*"} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
```

It ignores the comparison.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Sorry, i thought it could be read from the tags

Comment: escape the [ and ] with `

Comment: `` this seems to work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Escape the square brackets in the wildcard pattern with backticks:

```
... | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*`[TEST`]*"} | ...
```